# How can I add extra condition in laravel authentication?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am wondering how can I add extra condition like active in laravel authentication that comes with laravel? I could do that by doing authentication manually but if is there any possibilities to do it with default auth if I can say that ?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to add extra items in the array parameter, for example:

```
Auth::attempt([
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'some_field_name' => $some_value
]);
```

All items will be checked like `where($key, '=', $value)`.

Comment: Could you be more specific , I mean where exactly put this could ?

Comment: This is `if(Auth::attempt($array)) { // Login... }` for making the user logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If you override the `getCredentials` method of the AuthenticatesUsers trait in the AuthController, you can add extra conditional parameters:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');

        $credentials['active'] = 'y';
        return $credentials;
    }

    //Other code and methods here
}
```

This method provides the fields to be checked to the Attempt method. In the beginning of the file, you need to use the `Illuminate\Http\Request` namespace to work.

Comment: How can we add NOT and OR condition in the login auth query? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? Try to elaborate on your question, and add some code examples.

Comment: eg. `select * from users_table where email = 'abc@example.com' and password = '12345678' and status = '1' and (usertype = 'teacher' or usertype = 'parent')`. Kindly suggest how can we add this type of OR condition in Auth login? Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

I installed laravel breeze authentication starter kit.
You can add any extra users table column validation if you want by adding the column name and value in $credential array. See authenticate() in App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest.php .

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();
    $credentials =$this->only('username', 'password');
    $credentials['status'] = '1';
    

    if (! Auth::attempt($credentials, $this->filled('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'username' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

Comment: How can we add NOT and OR condition in the login auth query? Kindly suggest. Thanks.